# bluetooth fails to get enabled;  Unknown symbol security_sk_clone (err 0) in dmesg

Tags: bluetooth, lenovo

```
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu1110 3.0.0-14-generic-pae #23-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 21 22:07:10 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

laptop model: Lenovo W520

upon trying to enable bluetooth, the led turns on but, bluetooth is fails to get enabled in the preferences also seen below error message in dmesg

```
[78183.389048] usb 1-1.4: new full speed USB device number 19 using ehci_hcd
[78183.504129] bluetooth: Unknown symbol security_sk_clone (err 0)
[78183.505084] bluetooth: Unknown symbol security_sk_clone (err 0)
[78183.505189] bluetooth: Unknown symbol security_sk_clone (err 0)
[78183.505294] bluetooth: Unknown symbol security_sk_clone (err 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

My collegue just had this same issue on an Asus laptop after installing `linux-backports-modules-cw-3.1-3.0.0-14-generic` because his Bluetooth audio device would not connect (timeout). What solved the issue for him is installing the 3.2 kernel from Precise:

- Go to http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/linux-image
- Follow the link to the `*-generic` package
- Click `amd64` if you're running a 64-bit OS or `i386` for 32-bit machines
- Download the package from a mirror
- Install the `.deb` package

If you need to build out-of-tree modules (e.g. nvidia driver), you need to install two additional packages

- Go to http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/linux-headers-generic
- Follow the link to the `*-generic` package
- Choose a download on the `amd64` or `i386` page (open this in a new tab or window)
- Follow the link to the `linux-headers-*` package
- Choose a download on the `amd64` or `i386` page
- Install both `.deb` packages

There is obviously a better way to do this, but this works for now.